# Using PHP coding in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: php, sharepoint

I have loads of PHP-written pages that I'd like to host in Sharepoint without having to re-write them all in aspx.

Is it possible to use PHP coding on a Sharepoint aspx page?
If not, can you link a Sharepoint page to display a page written in PHP?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know SharePoint will not be able to directly delivery the php pages. However you can add script editor web part on SharePoint pages and show your php pages in iframe.